# Geometric Sums - Equivalency

Tags: sequences-and-series

Where $ar^0+ar^1+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4...=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^{n-1}=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{(1-r)}$

My question is: by this same definition, is it also true that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^{n}=\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{(1-r)}$?

Comment: There is a problem in your post, $n$ cannot appear in the final expression.

Comment: On top of that what is $r$ and $a$?

Comment: If you want to write the infinite sum like you did, you need to make sure that if $a \neq 0$ you have $|r|<1$.

Comment: Your first equation has errors.  The middle term should be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1}$ or $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n$

Answer (score 0):

I assume $a \neq 0$, and $|r|<1$ then:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} ar^{n-1} = \dfrac{a}{1-r}$$

This is the same thing as:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}ar^n = \dfrac{a}{1-r}$$

More generally if $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $q_0\leq N$ then:

$$ \sum_{n=q_0}^N ar^{n} = ar^{q_0}\dfrac{(1-r^{N-q_0+1})}{1-r}$$ and by changing the indexes:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N-q_0} ar^{n+q_0} = ar^{q_0}\dfrac{(1-r^{N-q_0+1})}{1-r}$$ so : $$\forall q_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \quad \sum_{n=q_0}^{+\infty}ar^n = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a r^{n+q_0} =\dfrac{ar^{q_0}}{1-r}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is incorrect, since $n$ is the dummy variable, so let's find a correct one.

Let $S=ar^0+ar^1+...$. Then $rS=ar^1+ar^2+...$. Thus $S-rS=ar^0=a\implies S(1-r)=a\implies S=\boxed{\frac{a}{1-r}}$. This only holds if $|r|<1$, otherwise the series diverges (goes to $\infty$).

For $ar^{n-1}$, the result is similar, we just need to add on the $ar^{-1}=\frac{a}{r}$ term.

Thus $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^n=\frac{a}{1-r}, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^{n-1}=\frac{a}{r}+\frac{a}{1-r}$, with $|r|<1$.